# Delete interrupted backups

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, macos

How can I access the files of an interrupted Time Machine backup to delete them for a fresh restart?

Unfortunately, there is nothing shown via <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> using Finder. However, when I search for files, there are apparently files in an hidden folder with the prefix `.interrupted`…

Comment: IIRC you can restart a Time Machine backup and any previously interrupted backups are sorted out and completed. There's no need to remove interrupted backups, unless maybe you need to exclude something from the beginning that you don't want in a backup.

Comment: Thanks, I know that this is generally handled by Time Machine - however these failed backups cover a lot of storage space, so I wanted to delete them manually.

Comment: Also, it seems that Time Machine hangs up at some point when creating a backup, so I am wondering if these failed backups are the reason for that.

Comment: On Sonoma 14.1.1 my network Time Machine backup attempts are getting stuck at 10% causing many of these interrupted folders, is that the issue you are facing?

Comment: No, this was still on macOS Ventura 13.6.1 - I wanted to do the backup before the update on Sonoma…

Answer (score -1):

Ok, it works via Terminal:

```
cd /Volumes/Name_of_Drive
sudo rm -r Date_of_Backup.interrupted
sudo rm -r Date_of_Backup.inprogress
```

As usual, use the command *rm -r* with caution: It deletes content permanently!

Comment: Time Machine often uses permissions which prevent its files being deleted with `rm` — even by the superuser.  However, they _can_ usually be deleted with `sudo tmutil delete`.

Comment: Thanks, I am precisely getting this problem with one of my ".interrupted" folders. Just to be clear: The correct command is `sudo tmutil delete -p Path_to_Folder`?

Comment: Ok, this does not work, I get the following error message: `Invalid deletion target (error 22)`

Comment: Hmmm, I don't remember using `-p`…  Can you try without (just `sudo tmutil delete <path>`?

Comment: The `-p` specifies that the following path should be deleted - without it, I get an error…

Comment: I have been able to delete several interrupted backups with the above command, however one 'backup' is still remaining. I get the impression that the problem is, that it has never been created properly, so it kind of does not exists to the degree that it can be deleted properly. Does this make sense?

Comment: @gidds - that comment on using tmutil should be an answer